# Make link using submit button

Tags: html, hyperlink

Can I link one page to another page using submit button?

Comment: Are you using JQuery, Dojo, Mootools or any Javascript framework?

Answer (score 3):

It sends all the wrong signals to the user, but:

```
<form action="some-uri"><div><input type="submit"></div></form>
```

Comment: i'm using dreamweaver cs3 and i just wondering if there is any possibility i can link age to page using submit button

Comment: This is no uncommon practice when you are going through a wizard with a Next button. Where the button than redirects you to the next step in the wizard. But you're answer is correct.

Comment: can i make a box that contains a word to link to another page?

Comment: @Peter — if you are going through a wizard, then you are submitting a form, and that is a normal form submission and not sending any wrong signals.

Comment: @lilian — Apply the CSS border property to a regular link.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using a submit form is that the next page will think that it has to deal with a binary request, which you can't do if using an upload form.

So you are better using a image button (can make it look like a submit button) or using JavaScript...

Open in a new window:

```
onClick="window.open('page.html');"
```

Open in the same window:

```
onClick="document.location.href = ('page.html');"
```